# Delete rows using case when condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Say I write this query

```
select
    x1, x2, x3 act
from 
    mytab
```

I need delete rows using any condition

```
case when x1=b, and act=0, then delete these rows
```

At the same time, i need to delete rows that contain a `null` value by `x1` column.

How can I do that?

Comment: The `DELETE` query would be `DELETE FROM dbo.mytab WHERE x1 = 'B' AND act=0 OR x1 IS NULL;`.

Answer (score 4):

You specified the condition in `WHERE` clause

for the condition that you required

```
DELETE d
FROM   mytab d
WHERE (
          d.x1 = 'b' AND d.act = 0
      )
OR    d.x1 is null
```

Comment: Why the parenthesis?

Comment: it is required for the `AND` conditions

Comment: Thanks, so it doesn't follow the standard operators priorities. In C I would write: x && y || z whitout parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL use where clause

```
DELETE FROM mytab 
WHERE x1 = b AND act=0 OR x1 IS NULL;;
```

Just execute this SQL and done. It will delete rows from database matching these conditions.

Answer (score 0):

For deleting rows,use `Delete` statement instead of `select` and the table name and then `where` clause for putting condition

```
 Detele t1
     from mytab t1
    where 
     (  x1=b  and act=0
     ) OR x1 IS NULL
```

here t1 is alias of table mytab